# In MATLAB, when is it optimal to use bsxfun?

Tags: arrays, matlab, bsxfun

I've noticed that a lot of good answers to MATLAB questions on Stack Overflow frequently use the function `bsxfun`. Why?

**Motivation:** In the MATLAB documentation for `bsxfun`, the following example is provided:

```
A = magic(5);
A = bsxfun(@minus, A, mean(A))
```

Of course we could do the same operation using:

```
A = A - (ones(size(A, 1), 1) * mean(A));
```

And in fact a simple speed test demonstrates the second method is about 20% faster. So why use the first method? I'm guessing there are some circumstances where using `bsxfun` will be much faster than the "manual" approach. I'd be really interested in seeing an example of such a situation and an explanation as to why it is faster.

Also, one final element to this question, again from the MATLAB documentation for `bsxfun`: "C = bsxfun(fun,A,B) applies the element-by-element binary operation specified by the function handle fun to arrays A and B, with singleton expansion enabled.". What does the phrase "with singleton expansion enabled" mean?

Comment: Note that the speed reading you get depends on the test you perform. If you run the above code after restarting Matlab and simply put `tic...toc` around the lines, the speed of the code will depend on having to read functions into memory.

Comment: @Jonas Yes, I just learned about this by reading about the `timeit` function in the link you/angainor/Dan provide.

Comment: Note that now (since R16b), `bsxfun` has been superseded by implicit expansion, see [Is bsxfun still optimal in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70106927/is-bsxfun-still-optimal-in-matlab)

Answer (score 153, accepted):

There are three reasons I use `bsxfun` ([documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), [blog link](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/08/04/comparing-repmat-and-bsxfun-performance/))

1. `bsxfun` is faster than `repmat` (see below)
2. `bsxfun` requires less typing
3. Using `bsxfun`, like using `accumarray`, makes me feel good about my understanding of MATLAB.

`bsxfun` will replicate the input arrays along their "singleton dimensions", i.e., the dimensions along which the size of the array is 1, so that they match the size of the corresponding dimension of the other array. This is what is called "[singleton expansion](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/gpuarray.bsxfun.html)". As an aside, the singleton dimensions are the ones that will be dropped if you call `squeeze`.

It is possible that for very small problems, the `repmat` approach is faster - but at that array size, both operations are so fast that it likely won't make any difference in terms of overall performance. There are two important reasons `bsxfun` is faster: (1) the calculation happens in compiled code, which means that the actual replication of the array never happens, and (2) `bsxfun` is one of the multithreaded MATLAB functions.

I have run a speed comparison between `repmat` and `bsxfun` with MATLAB R2012b on my decently fast laptop.

[image]

For me, `bsxfun` is about three times faster than `repmat`. The difference becomes more pronounced if the arrays get larger:

[image]

The jump in runtime of `repmat` happens around an array size of 1 MB, which could have something to do with the size of my processor cache - `bsxfun` doesn't get as bad of a jump, because it only needs to allocate the output array.

Below you find the code I used for timing:

```
n = 300;
k=1; %# k=100 for the second graph
a = ones(10,1);
rr = zeros(n,1);
bb = zeros(n,1);
ntt = 100;
tt = zeros(ntt,1);
for i=1:n;
   r = rand(1,i*k);
   for it=1:ntt;
      tic,
      x = bsxfun(@plus,a,r);
      tt(it) = toc;
   end;
   bb(i) = median(tt);
   for it=1:ntt;
      tic,
      y = repmat(a,1,i*k) + repmat(r,10,1);
      tt(it) = toc;
   end;
   rr(i) = median(tt);
end
```

Comment: Thank you for an excellent response +1. I've marked this the answer as it is the most comprehensive discussion and has also (at this point) received the most up-votes.

Answer (score 41):

In my case, I use `bsxfun` because it avoids me to think about the column or row issues.

In order to write your example:

```
A = A - (ones(size(A, 1), 1) * mean(A));
```

I have to solve several problems:

1. `size(A,1)` or `size(A,2)`
2. `ones(sizes(A,1),1)` or `ones(1,sizes(A,1))`
3. `ones(size(A, 1), 1) * mean(A)` or `mean(A)*ones(size(A, 1), 1)`
4. `mean(A)` or `mean(A,2)`

When I use `bsxfun`, I just have to solve the last one:

a) `mean(A)` or `mean(A,2)`

You might think it is lazy or something, but when I use `bsxfun`, I have **fewer bugs** and I **program faster**.

Moreover, it is shorter, which improves **typing speed** and **readability**.

Comment: Thanks for the response Oli. +1 as I think this answer contributed something in addition to the responses of angainor and Jonas. I particularly liked the way you laid out the number of conceptual problems that need to be solved in a given line of code.

Answer (score 17):

Very interesting question! I have recently stumbled upon exactly such situation while answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867524/matlab-calculation-on-subset-of-vector-then-shift-and-repeat/12872704#12872704). Consider the following code that computes indices of a sliding window of size 3 through a vector `a`:

```
a = rand(1e7, 1);

tic;
idx = bsxfun(@plus, [0:2]', 1:numel(a)-2);
toc

% Equivalent code from im2col function in MATLAB
tic;
idx0 = repmat([0:2]', 1, numel(a)-2);
idx1 = repmat(1:numel(a)-2, 3, 1);
idx2 = idx0+idx1;
toc;

isequal(idx, idx2)

Elapsed time is 0.297987 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.501047 seconds.

ans =

 1
```

In this case `bsxfun` is almost twice faster! It is useful and fast because it **avoids explicit allocation of memory** for matrices `idx0` and `idx1`, saving them to the memory, and then reading them again just to add them. Since memory bandwidth is a valuable asset and often the bottleneck on today's architectures, you want to use it wisely and decrease the memory requirements of your code to improve the performance.

`bsxfun` allows you to do just that: create a matrix based on applying an arbitrary operator to all pairs of elements of two vectors, instead of operating explicitly on two matrices obtained by replicating the vectors. That is *singleton expansion*. You can also think about it as the **outer product** from [BLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms):

```
v1=[0:2]';
v2 = 1:numel(a)-2;
tic;
vout = v1*v2;
toc
Elapsed time is 0.309763 seconds.
```

You multiply two vectors to obtain a matrix. Just that the outer product only performs multiplication, and `bsxfun` can apply arbitrary operators. As a side note, it is very interesting to see that `bsxfun` is as fast as the BLAS outer product. And BLAS is usually considered to deliver **the** performance...

Thanks to Dan's comment, here is a great [article by Loren](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/08/04/comparing-repmat-and-bsxfun-performance/) discussing exactly that.

Comment: This article might be relevant: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/08/04/comparing-repmat-and-bsxfun-performance/

Comment: @Dan Thanks for a great reference.

Comment: Thanks for a great response angainor. +1 for being the first to clearly state the main advantage of `bsxfun` with a good example.

Answer (score 17):

As of R2016b, MATLAB supports [*Implicit Expansion*](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#bu90yi3-1) for a wide variety of operators, so in most cases it is no longer necessary to use `bsxfun`:

> Previously, this functionality was available via the `bsxfun` function.
> It is now recommended that you replace most uses of `bsxfun` with direct
> calls to the functions and operators that support *implicit expansion*.
> Compared to using `bsxfun`, *implicit expansion* offers **faster speed**,
> **better memory usage**, and **improved readability of code**.

There's a [detailed discussion](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/) of *Implicit Expansion* and its performance on Loren's blog. To [quote](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/#comment-46516) Steve Eddins from [MathWorks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathWorks):

> In R2016b, *implicit expansion* works as fast or faster than `bsxfun` in most cases. The best performance gains for *implicit expansion* are with small matrix and array sizes. For large matrix sizes, implicit expansion tends to be roughly the same speed as `bsxfun`.

Answer (score 9):

Things are not always consistent with the 3 common methods: `repmat`, expension by ones indexing, and `bsxfun`. It gets rather more interesting when you increase the vector size even further. See plot:

[image: comparison]

`bsxfun` actually becomes slightly slower than the other two at some point, but what surprised me is if you increase the vector size even more (>13E6 output elements), bsxfun suddenly becomes faster again by about 3x. Their speeds seem to jump in steps and the order are not always consistent. My guess is it could be processor/memory size dependent too, but generally I think I'd stick with `bsxfun` whenever possible.