# Image Cropping with a Matrix Filter

Tags: image, matlab

After some processing, I got a black&white mask of a BMP image.

Now, I want to show only the part of the BMP image where it is white in the mask.

I'm a newb with matlab(but I love it), and I've tried a lot of matrix tricks learned from google, well, none works(or I'm not doing them right ..)

Please provide me with some tips.

Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the mask is of the same size as image, then you can just do (for grayscale images):

```
maskedImage=yourImage.*mask %.* means pointwise multiplication.
```

For color images, do the same operations on the three channels:

```
maskedImage(:,:,1)=yourImage(:,:,1).*mask 
maskedImage(:,:,2)=yourImage(:,:,2).*mask 
maskedImage(:,:,3)=yourImage(:,:,3).*mask
```

Then to visualize the image, do:

```
imshow(maskedImage,[]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using one of the two matlab functions [repmat](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) or [bsxfun](http://www.mathworks.se/help/distcomp/bsxfun.html) the masking operation can be performed in a single line of code for a source image with any number of channels.

Assuming that your image `I` is of size `M-by-N-by-C` and the mask is of size `M-by-N`, then we can obtain the masked image using either repmat

```
I2 = I .* repmat(mask, [1, 1, 3]);
```

or using bsxfun

```
I2 = bsxfun(@times, I, mask);
```

These are both very handy functions to know about and can be very useful when it comes to vectorizing your code in general. I would also recommend that you look through the answer to this question: [In Matlab, when is it optimal to use bsxfun?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951453/in-matlab-when-is-it-optimal-to-use-bsxfun)