# Counting occurrences of a vector for each row of a matrix

Tags: matlab

Given a vector `v = [2 2]` I am trying to find how many times it is present in a matrix, say

`data_2 =`

```
 2     2
 2     2
 1     2
 2     2
 2     1
 1     2
 2     1
 1     1
 2     2
 2     2
```

In the above dummy example, `[2 2]` occurs in 5 rows out of total 10 rows present. The following code should ideally be giving me the same answer -

`numel(find(data_2 == repmat(v,size(data_2,1),1)))`

However the answer for the above is 14. Logically I am trying to simply count occurrences, but I must have messed up with the MATLAB commands. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), then [`all`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/all.html) row-wise, then [`sum`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sum.html):

```
sum(all(bsxfun(@eq, v, data_2),2))
```

Or use [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) with the `'rows'` option and then `sum`:

```
sum(ismember(data_2,v,'rows'))
```

---

Your approach is similar to my first solution (`bsxfun` is essentially an implicit, faster `repmat`; see [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/08/04/comparing-repmat-and-bsxfun-performance/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12955706/2586922)). The problem with your code is that it counts each column separately. A row-wise `all` is needed to combine the results of all columns into a single result per row:

```
numel(find(all((data_2 == repmat(v,size(data_2,1),1)),2)))
```

or better use `sum(...)` instead of `numel(find(...))`:

```
sum(all((data_2 == repmat(v,size(data_2,1),1)),2))
```

Comment: Thanks. I figured out the element-wise comparison instead of row-wise. Ending up using `ismember` - more intuitive.