# Using row vector to updated values in matrix

Tags: vectorization, octave

I have a matrix and a row vector produced by the [std function](http://octave.sourceforge.net/nan/function/std.html):

```
X = [1 2 3; 4 5 6];
sigma = std(X);
```

Now I would like a vectorized solution that updates each value in X by dividing the value with the correct value in sigma. It would look something like this:

```
X(1,1)/sigma(1)
X(1,2)/sigma(2)
X(1,3)/sigma(3)
X(2,1)/sigma(1)
X(2,2)/sigma(2)
X(2,3)/sigma(3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just expand sigma and use elementwise division

```
Y = X ./ repmat (sigma, rows (X), 1)
Y =

   0.47140   0.94281   1.41421
   1.88562   2.35702   2.82843
```

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant solution would be to use [bsxfun](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/bsxfun.html), which is faster and cleaner than `repmat`.
The topic has been extensively covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951453/in-matlab-when-is-it-optimal-to-use-bsxfun).

```
> bsxfun(@rdivide,X,sigma)
ans =

   0.47140   0.94281   1.41421
   1.88562   2.35702   2.82843
```