# Matlab recursive function to generate a matrix

Tags: matlab, recursion, matrix

I'm struggling with this task:

Create a recursive function that takes n as an argument and creates a matrix like this, in this case n = 3:

```
 0     1     2     3     2     1     0
 1     1     2     3     2     1     1
 2     2     2     3     2     2     2
 3     3     3     3     3     3     3
```

I already came up with this:

```
function AA =  A(n)
    if n == 0
        AA (1,1) = 0;
    else
        AA = n*ones(n+1,2*n+1);
        AA(1:n, [1:n, n+3:end]) = A(n-1);
    end  
end
```

But the output seems to have a weird shift on the RHS:

```
 0     1     2     3     3     2     1
 1     1     2     3     3     2     1
 2     2     2     3     3     2     2
 3     3     3     3     3     3     3
```

Can someone help?

Comment: What should it look like for `n=2` or `n=4`? I'm mostly confused by the middle column of just `3`s.

Comment: Is this an assignment /do you have to use recursion?

Comment: Makes more sense, though the most sense would have been two columns of threes in the middle...

Comment: Just a first comment, is your base case correct? What should be the output for `n==0`? Should it be `[0]` or `[0, 0]`? I think your problem isn't that you have a shift, but that you're missing your last column.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think both answers already existing can be simplified. For the recursive solution use:

```
function AA =  A(n)
    if n == 0
        AA = 0;
    else
        h=A(n-1);
        AA = n*ones(n+1,2*n+1);
        AA(1:n,1:n)=h(:,1:n);
        AA(1:n,n+2:end)=h(:,n:end);
    end  
end
```

The important point is to index the column `n` of the intermediate result twice to duplicate it, one in `h(:,1:n)` and once in `h(:,n:end)`.

If you are looking for a vectorized / faster solution simply use:

```
bsxfun(@max,[0:N-1].',[0:N-1 N-2:-1:0])
```

For MATLAB 2016b or later, [implicit expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39925305/2732801) can be used:

```
max([0:N-1].',[0:N-1 N-2:-1:0])
```

Comment: perfect, greetings from Aachen ;)

Answer (score 4):

I have a no loop answer which is a little unorthodox, but it works fine and is very fun to write (or to say I am bored at work at the moment)..

```
N =3;
A = repmat(0:N,N+1,1);
M = triu(A,1);
B = repmat((0:N)',1,N+1);
L = fliplr(flipud(triu(flipud(B))));
P = M+L;
Rep = fliplr(P(:,1:N));
answer = [P,Rep];
```

This one uses the `triu` to generate the progressive pattern in the matrix, and does some fun constructing to create the final matrix:

```
N = 2;

answer =

 0     1     2     1     0
 1     1     2     1     1
 2     2     2     2     2

N = 4;

answer =

 0     1     2     3     4     3     2     1     0
 1     1     2     3     4     3     2     1     1
 2     2     2     3     4     3     2     2     2
 3     3     3     3     4     3     3     3     3
 4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4
```

Advantage: Uses no loop, will definitely be faster for large N I assume.I highly advise running line by line to see what the output is, so you understand how it is constructed step by step.

Comment: Fun indeed but `No loop != faster`

Comment: @percusse of course :D but I assumed that matrix operations such as flip and sum should be very quick operations.