# MATLAB - convert vector to unit vector

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a vector:

```
vector = [1 2 3;4 5 6; 7 9 0]
vector =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     9     0
```

I want to take this and create a unit vector. We can get the magnitude by doing:

```
mag = sqrt(sum(vector'.^2))'

mag =

    3.7417
    8.7750
   11.4018
```

When we try to divide each element by the magnitude I get an error:

```
vector./mag
Error using  ./ 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
```

Essentially I must divide every vector element in each row by every row in the mag vector. How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The other answers give the correct result but you can vectorize the calculation for faster calculation.

```
ret = bsxfun(@rdivide, vector, mag)
```

I recommend using the `bsxfun`, it is a very useful function for matrix calculation.

Comment: Just did a quick timing on bsxfun versus repmat in Octave:
    `>> tic; zeros(10000,10000) + repmat((1:10000)',1,10000); toc
    Elapsed time is 1.18 seconds.`

    `>> tic; bsxfun(@plus, zeros(10000,10000), (1:10000)'); toc
    Elapsed time is 0.726 seconds.`

Comment: @stephematician `bsxfun` is always faster.  See this related article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951453/in-matlab-when-is-it-optimal-to-use-bsxfun

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that, as the error message says, the dimensions of `vector` and `mag` don't match.
You want to divide every element of the first row of `vector` by `mag(1)`.
What you need is [`repmat()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html), which "repeats copies of array".
Writing

```
repmat(mag,1,3)
```

returns a `3x3` matrix such that every column is an exact copy of `mag`:

```
    3.7417    3.7417    3.7417
    8.7750    8.7750    8.7750
   11.4018   11.4018   11.4018
```

So you can use the one-liner:

```
vector./repmat(mag,1,3)
ans =

   0.26726   0.53452   0.80178
   0.45584   0.56980   0.68376
   0.61394   0.78935   0.00000
```

That way, the first row of `vector`, i.e., `[1 2 3]`, is divided element-by-element by `[3.7417 3.7417 3.7417]`.
In other words, every element of `vector` is divided by the correct magnitude.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is the use of a for-loop:

```
vector = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 9 0];
mag = sqrt(sum(vector'.^2))';
A = [];
for i = 1:numel(mag)
    A(i,:) = vector(i,:)./mag(i);
end
```

Comment: A for loop is almost never the best option in Matlab when considering vector operations.

Comment: The problem here is not the for loop (which as you said it might give comparable results to bsxfun) but the preallocation of `A`. If you don't preallocate it will for sure be way slower.

Answer (score 2):

You can use matrix operators in MATLAB:

```
result = diag(1./mag)*vector;
```

If dimension of `mag` can be too big you can use sparse version of it:

```
result = spdiags(1./mag,0,speye(numel(mag)))*vector;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
vector = [1 2 3; 4 5 6 ;7 9 0] ;

[n,m]=size(vector);

for i=1:n
normv=norm(vector(i,:),2);
nvector(i,:)=vector(i,:)/normv;
end
```

the *nvector* will contain the normalized vector of each line

Comment: Other than the explicit call to `norm` to find the magnitude, this answer isn't any different from the others seen so far here.