# How to create a symmetric matrix where each row/column is a subset of a known vector

Tags: matlab, matrix, diagonal, symmetry

I have a 7*1 vector `a = (1:7).'`. I want to form a matrix `A` of size 4*4 from vector `a` such that the elements of `a` form the anti-diagonals of matrix `A` as follows:

```
A = [1 2 3 4;
     2 3 4 5;
     3 4 5 6;
     4 5 6 7]
```

I would like this to work for a general `a`, not just when the elements are consecutive integers.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `hankel`:

```
n= 4;
A= hankel(a(1:n),a(n:2*n-1))
```

Other solution(expansion/bsxfun):

In MATLAB r2016b /Octave It can be created as:

```
A = a((1:4)+(0:3).')
```

In pre r2016b you can use `bsxfun`:

```
A = a(bsxfun(@plus,1:4, (0:3).'))
```

Example input/output

```
a = [4 6 2 7 3 5 1]

A =

   4   6   2   7
   6   2   7   3
   2   7   3   5
   7   3   5   1
```

Using the benchmark provided by @Wolfie tested  in Octave:

```
 _____________________________________
|Method   |memory peak(MB)|timing(Sec)|
|=========|===============|===========|
|bsxfun   |2030           |1.50       |
|meshgrid |3556           |2.43       |
|repmat   |2411           |2.64       |
|hankel   |886            |0.43       |
|for loop |886            |0.82       |
```

Answer (score 6):

#### Setting up the indexing

Adding the two outputs of `meshgrid` can give the indices:

```
[x, y] = meshgrid(1:4, 0:3);
x + y;
% ans = [1     2     3     4
%        2     3     4     5
%        3     4     5     6
%        4     5     6     7];
```

If `a` was just as in your example you could stop there. Alternatively, use this to index a general vector `a`. For comparison, I'll use the same example input as rahnema1 did for their method:

```
a = [4 6 2 7 3 5 1];
[x, y] = meshgrid(1:4, 0:3);
A = a(x + y);    
% A = [4     6     2     7
%      6     2     7     3
%      2     7     3     5
%      7     3     5     1]
```

There are *many* ways you could create the indices instead of using `meshgrid`, see the benchmarking functions below for some exampels!

---

#### Benchmarking and seven different methods.

Here are some timings for running different methods, including methods using `cumsum`, `repmat`, `hankel` and a simple `for` loop. This benchmark was done in Matlab 2015b, so takes advantage of Matlab optimisations etc. which the Octave benchmarks in rahnema1's answer might not do. I also use the `timeit` function which is more robust than `tic`/`toc` because it does multiple trials etc.

```
function benchie()
    n = 10000;    % (large) square matrix size
    a = 1:2*n-1;  % array of correct size, could be anything this long
    f1 = @() m1(a,n);  disp(['bsxfun:   ', num2str(timeit(f1))]);
    f2 = @() m2(a,n);  disp(['cumsum:   ', num2str(timeit(f2))]);
    f3 = @() m3(a,n);  disp(['meshgrid: ', num2str(timeit(f3))]);
    f4 = @() m4(a,n);  disp(['repmat:   ', num2str(timeit(f4))]);
    f5 = @() m5(a,n);  disp(['for loop: ', num2str(timeit(f5))]);
    f6 = @() m6(a,n);  disp(['hankel1:  ', num2str(timeit(f6))]); 
    f7 = @() m7(a,n);  disp(['hankel2:  ', num2str(timeit(f7))]); 
end
% Use bsxfun to do broadcasting of addition
function m1(a,n); A = a(bsxfun(@plus, (1:n), (0:n-1).')); end
% Use cumsum to do cumulative vertical addition to create indices
function m2(a,n); A = a(cumsum([(1:n); ones(n-1,n)])); end
% Add the two meshgrid outputs to get indices
function m3(a,n); [x, y] = meshgrid(1:n, 0:n-1); A = a(x + y); end
% Use repmat twice to replicate the meshgrid results, for equivalent one liner
function m4(a,n); A = a(repmat((1:n)',1,n) + repmat(0:n-1,n,1)); end
% Use a simple for loop. Initialise A and assign values to each row in turn
function m5(a,n); A = zeros(n); for ii = 1:n; A(:,ii) = a(ii:ii+n-1); end; end
% Create a Hankel matrix (constant along anti-diagonals) for indexing
function m6(a,n); A = a(hankel(1:n,n:2*n-1)); end
% Create a Hankel matrix directly from elements
function m7(a,n); A = hankel(a(1:n),a(n:2*n-1)); end
```

Output:

```
bsxfun:   1.4397 sec
cumsum:   2.0563 sec
meshgrid: 2.0169 sec
repmat:   1.8598 sec
for loop: 0.4953 sec % MUCH quicker!
hankel1:  2.6154 sec
hankel2:  1.4235 sec
```

So you are best off using rahnema1's suggestion of `bsxfun` or direct generation of a `hankel` matrix if you want a one liner, here is a brilliant StackOverflow answer which explains some of `bsxfun`'s advantages: [In Matlab, when is it optimal to use bsxfun?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12955706/3978545)

**However, the for loop is more than twice as quick!** Conclusion: Matlab has lots of neat ways to achieve things like this, sometimes a simple for loop with some appropriate pre-allocation and Matlab's internal optimisations can be the quickest.

Comment: @snat I recommend trying the above benchmark to see which is quickest on your machine and version of Matlab! Mileage may vary